# SBT is installing dependencies from package.json

Tags: playframework, sbt

I'm unsure if this is a bug or something that I have activated somehow. Basically I have Play Framework app that doesn't like running tests when I have a `package.json` file in the root folder. Everything runs fine when I just `run` the app.  I have had no luck finding anyone with the same kind of problem as me.

Running `test` inside sbt runs fine when `package.json` is **not present**. If `package.json` is present, SBT begins to install/download these dependencies to `/node_modules` and they corrupt my already installed npm modules. I have to do a reinstall afterwards to get my npm modules working again.

This is the error message I get multiple times in the console.

```
Exception in thread "Trireme Async Pool" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/home/anders/vidme/node_modules/grunt-ts/node_modules/.bin/rimraf" "readlink")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readSymbolicLink(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:487)
at java.nio.file.Files.readSymbolicLink(Files.java:1384)
at io.apigee.trireme.core.modules.AsyncFilesystem$FSImpl.doReadLink(AsyncFilesystem.java:1470)
at io.apigee.trireme.core.modules.AsyncFilesystem$FSImpl.access$2000(AsyncFilesystem.java:118)
at io.apigee.trireme.core.modules.AsyncFilesystem$FSImpl$26.execute(AsyncFilesystem.java:1459)
at io.apigee.trireme.core.modules.AsyncFilesystem$FSImpl$1.run(AsyncFilesystem.java:201)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-ts": "~4.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.9.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.4.0"
  }
}
```

`build.sbt`

```
name := """vidme"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "app"

scalaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test"

sourcesInBase := false

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws,
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10.5.0.akka23",
  "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.8.0",
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4" % "test",
  "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0"
)
```

Is there anyway I can stop this from happening? I tried adding `scalaSource` in my sbt file, but that changed nothing.

Comment: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-js-engine is what is calling this. Not sure how to disable it though.